# How to grant access to a User on SharePoint document library/ list using Power automate or Rest API

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, power-automate, csom, sharepoint-rest-api

I'm working on a automation where we want to give access to a requested user on a SharePoint document library and list.
We are using Power automates for end to end automation but dint find any way to achieve the problem statement.
Can i get some leads.